# $\alpha$-Hölder continuous holomorphic function on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function on the unit disk such that for some $C > 0$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ we have
$$\vert f(z) - f(w) \vert \leq C \vert z - w \vert^{\alpha}$$
for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$.

Show that
$$\vert f'(z) \vert \leq A\vert 1 - \vert z \vert \vert^{\alpha - 1}$$
for some constant $A > 0$ depending only on $C$.

Dividing both sides of the given inequality by $\vert z - w \vert$ we get
$$\frac{\vert f(z) - f(w) \vert}{\vert z - w\vert} \leq C\vert z - w \vert^{\alpha - 1} \leq C \vert \vert z \vert - \vert w \vert \vert^{\alpha - 1}.$$
It seems like we want to replace the $w$ on the right-hand side by $1$ somehow and replace the left-hand side by some constant multiple of $\vert f'(z) \vert$, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I would appreciate hints over full solutions.

Answer (score 5):

I think $A=C$ works. Fix $z$. Let $g(w)=\frac {f(w)-f(z)} {w-z}$ for $w \neq z$ and $g(z)=f'(z)$. Then $g$ is holomorphic. We have $|g(w)| \leq C|w-z|^{\alpha -1} \leq C(1- \epsilon -|z|)^{\alpha -1}$ for $|w|=1-\epsilon$ (because $|w-z| \geq |w|-|z|$ and $\alpha -1 <0$). By Maximum Modulus Principle it follows that the same true for $|w| \leq 1-\epsilon$. In particular we get $|f'(z)| \leq C(1- \epsilon -|z|)^{\alpha -1}$. Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ completes the proof.